# Why does server break utf-8 characters from DB?

Tags: php, mysql

Remote server: CentOS 7/ Apache 2.4 / PHP 7/ MYSQL 5.7

Everything works well when I run my php web application on local server, connecting to remote DB, but when I launch it on remote Apache/PHP, I see that special utf-8 chars are broken.

I wonder why it is happening only when PHP is running on VDS?

I use PDO_MYSQL and now see that ;charset=utf8  in DSN has solved the problem. But on my local PC I don;t need it in DSN. Why? How can I set utf 8 by default on remote server/PHP?

I have this in my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]

... 

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

init_connect=‘SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci’
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci

[client]
default-character-set = utf8
```

But as far as I understand the problem is not with MySQL... is it?

Comment: I think you need to explain your problem more. *How* are your utf-8 chars broken? When does it happen and where? etc.

Comment: For example '«' becomes '�' in entries' text. Als serialized data becomes non-unserializable